# Factors affecting magnitude of induced emf in coil

Tags: electromagnetism

Does the magnitude of emf induced in a coil depend only on the rate of change of flux?

Does it depend also on the amount of flux linked to it?

Will the change of flux from $50 ~H$ to $40 ~H$ and $10 ~H$ to $0 ~H$ produce same e.m.f?

Answer (score 1):

> I mean will flux chng from 50H to 40H and 10H to 0H produce same e.m.f?

Yes, if the *rate of change* or the *velocity of change* is the same in both cases and the coil have same number of turns.
To sum up, *rate of change of flux with respect to time* produces an emf regardless of the amount of flux. The quantitative rule goes by the name ***[Faraday's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction).***